# Function onChangeAnswers in the checkbox what he does

Tags: node.js, reactjs

i have two function in my code which are used in checkbox, This panel allows you to add questions to the database, if you select the checkbox is true, it will enter true into the database, and if you do not select it, then false. but i don't know what they are doing, please step for step description, what doing this code.

```
const onChangeAnswers = (type, index) => (e) => {
    const { value, checked } = e.target;

    const { answears } = formState;
    answears[index][type] = type === "isCorrect" ? checked : value
    setFormState({
      ...formState,
      answears
    })
  };

  const addNewAnswearField = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault()
    setFormState({
      ...formState,
      answears: [
        ...formState.answears,
        {
          isCorrect: false,
          answear: ''
        }
      ]
    })
  }
```

I use this function at checkbox

```
{formState.answears.map((answear, index) => (
          <Form.Group controlId="formBasicAnswer">
            <div>
              <Form.Label className="label-question">answer for question</Form.Label>
              <Form.Control type="text"
                placeholder="Odpowiedź"
                onChange={onChangeAnswers('answear', index)} />
              <Form.Text className="text-muted" >
                Add answer for question.
            </Form.Text>
            </div>
            <div>
              <Form.Label className="label-question">Is correct?</Form.Label>
              <Form.Control type="checkbox"
                onChange={onChangeAnswers('isCorrect', index)} />
              <Form.Text className="text-muted" >
                Add answer for question.
            </Form.Text>
            </div>



<button onClick={addNewAnswearField}>Add next field for answer</button>
```

Comment: Did you not write this code yourself? Is there a more specific issue, or aspect, other than "I don't understand this code" that is tripping you up?

Comment: That's right, I didn't write it myself, and I'd like to know what is happening step by step

Comment: Has my answer sufficiently addressed your question(s)? Is it clear what is occurring step-by-step?

Answer (score 1):

## onChangeAnswers

> ```
> const onChangeAnswers = (type, index) => (e) => {
>   const { value, checked } = e.target;
>
>   const { answears } = formState;
>   answears[index][type] = type === "isCorrect" ? checked : value
>   setFormState({
>     ...formState,
>     answears
>   })
> };
> ```

`onChangeAnswers` is a curried function, currying `type` and `index`, and returning an event handler callback function to be attached to an event handler. This encloses `type` and `index` in the callback scope and simplifies the callback. I.e. `onChangeAnswers('type', 0)` instead of something like `e => onChangeAnswers('type', 0, e)`.

```
const onChangeAnswers = (type, index) => (e) => {
  // (1) unpack the event object's checked or value properties
  const { value, checked } = e.target;

  // (2) declare a destructured answears from the formState object
  const { answears } = formState;

  // (3) update the property using dynamic keys
  answears[index][type] = type === "isCorrect" ? checked : value;

  // (4) shallow copy formState and merge in answears object
  setFormState({
    ...formState,
    answears
  })
};
```

## addNewAnswearField

> ```
> const addNewAnswearField = (e) => {
>   e.preventDefault()
>   setFormState({
>     ...formState,
>     answears: [
>       ...formState.answears,
>       {
>         isCorrect: false,
>         answear: ''
>       }
>     ]
>   })
> }
> ```

```
const addNewAnswearField = (e) => {
  // (1) prevent any default actions based on containing parent
  // nodes, i.e. buttons submitting any forms, etc...
  e.preventDefault();

  // (2) Add a new answer object
  setFormState({
    ...formState,            // <-- shallow copy state
    answears: [              // <-- declare new answears array
      ...formState.answears, // <-- shallow copy old array into new array
      {                      // <-- append new object
        isCorrect: false,
        answear: ''
      }
    ]
  })
}
```